# Social sharing links are not sharing correct data

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, google-plus, pinterest

I am trying to share my page on Twitter, Google+, Facebook, Pinterest and Linkedin but it's not sharing correct data. (I also need to share dynamic data in inner pages, but I'll do that after fix this).

I am using this documentation:
http://socialsharekit.com/#documentation

My code is:

```
// init library
<script type="text/javascript">
   SocialShareKit.init({
      selector: '.ssk-group .ssk',
      url: '{{url()}}', // this is url of my home page
      text: '{{$textToShare}}' // text to share
   });
</script>

// html links
<a href="" class="ssk ssk-facebook" data-url="{{url()}}" data-image="http://bucksme.com/images/logo.png" data-text="{{$textToShare}}" data-title="Bucksme - Everyone gets to save"></a>
<a href="" class="ssk ssk-twitter" data-url="{{url()}}" data-image="http://bucksme.com/images/logo.png" data-text="{{$textToShare}}" data-title="Bucksme - Everyone gets to save"></a>
<a href="" class="ssk ssk-google-plus" data-url="{{url()}}" data-image="http://bucksme.com/images/logo.png" data-text="{{$textToShare}}" data-title="Bucksme - Everyone gets to save"></a>
<a href="" class="ssk ssk-pinterest" data-url="{{url()}}" data-image="http://bucksme.com/images/logo.png" data-text="{{$textToShare}}" data-title="Bucksme - Everyone gets to save"></a>
<a href="" class="ssk ssk-linkedin" data-url="{{url()}}" data-image="http://bucksme.com/images/logo.png" data-text="{{$textToShare}}" data-title="Bucksme - Everyone gets to save"></a>
```

It's not sharing the correct data that I want to share.

If there is any another library for this use (that will show count and also able to share dynamic data) then please let me know. I can also use any paid library, but need demo first.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: its working but not sharing correct data, facebook is sharing an image that I have not provided, and sharing text that is not is meta tags and I also not provided that. You can check this on http://bucksme.com

Comment: @AnshulMishra: please try to write questions without links to your site. We want questions to make sense for future readers, so given that you will fix the problem in the links you supply, the question will not make any sense just as soon as you've fixed it. Therefore, if you can put all relevant material into the question itself, that is best. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer: thanks for that, I'll remember this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite get your question but I have looked into your site and found no Open Graph meta tags or protocol which are important for facebook and google+ to scrape your desired content.

Facebook Content Sharing Best Practices: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

For google+:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everything is working fine by adding the meta tags :) Can you please help me a bit more, I am unable to share correct image on google plus I have tried a lot for that. Can you please look once at http://www.bucksme.com